# Convert decimal(4,2) to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm have a situation where a `decimal(4,2)` time value needs converting to `time()`.

Where it appears to be unique, is a decimal time value of 14.25 should be 14:25, not 14:15.

I am unable to change the data in the CRM so must do all transformations in SQL Server, ideally as a Computed Column Specification in the Table Designer but if it can only be achieved in the SELECT statement that will do.

Below are some examples:

| Source Data | Needed Result |
| --- | --- |
| 14.25 | 14:25 |
| 8.09 | 08:09 |
| 10.10 | 10:10 |

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: What to do with values like 93.67?

Comment: the Source Data is by convention HH.MM ?

Comment: The thing you're trying to convert is the string representation of the decimal, not the decimal itself. So you need to convert to string, replace the decimal separator, then convert to time. And hope there are no invalid values.

Comment: I assume a plain replace is not what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Assuming* that the `decimal` can only contain valid `time` values you could do something like this:

```sql
TIMEFROMPARTS(CONVERT(int,YourColumn),(YourColumn % 1) * 100,0,0,0)
```

If there could be invalid values, and the value `NULL` is acceptable for bad value, such as `24.15` or `9.63` then you could do something like this:

```sql
TRY_CONVERT(time(0),REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),YourColumn),'.',':'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56040e0d5a5fae633c7abcd0ca5bec6d)

Either of these can be used as an expression for a computed columnnas well, though you may need to explicitly provide a style code for the `TRY_CONVERT` in the latter for it to be `PERSISTED`.

Comment: CAST(REPLACE(CAST([Source data] AS VARCHAR(16)), '.', ':') AS TIME) AS [Needed Result].  CAST and REPLACE are ANSI compliant function, while CONVERT, TRY_CONVERT are MS SQL Specific

Comment: `CAST`, however, isn't deterministic with date (and time) values though, @SQLpro and thus in a computed column `CONVERT` and `TRY_CONVERT` are normally better options.

Comment: ```TRY_CONVERT(time(0),REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),YourColumn),'.',':'))``` was absolutely spot on for what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SET NeededResult = REPLACE(SourceData, '.', ':')